# Call jQuery validate plugin inside jquery class (OOP concept)

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, oop

I want to use OOP concept in jQuery so i make one JQuery class names "AlcoholOrder". I am validating one form using jquery validation plugin.

```
/*
 * myClass
 */
var AlcoholOrder = function (options) {

    /*
     * Variables accessible
     * in the class
     */
    var vars = {
        myVar: 'original Value'
    };

    /*
     * Can access this.method
     * inside other methods using
     * root.method()
     */
    var root = this;

    /*
     * Constructor
     */
    this.construct = function (options) {
        $.extend(vars, options);
    };

    /*
     * Pass options when class instantiated
     */
    this.construct(options);

$(function () {
    $('#login').validate({
            rules: {
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email:true,
                },
                password: {
                        required: true
                },
            },
            messages: {
                email: {
                    required: "Email can not be blank.",
                },
                password:{
                    required:"Password can not be blank."
                }
            }
    });
});

};
```

I have added jquery like below

```
<?php echo base_url().'assets/js/jquery.js';?>
<?php echo base_url().'assets/js/jquery-validation/js/jquery.validate.min.js';?>
<?php echo base_url().'assets/js/alcohol.js'; ?>
```

Now i am getting error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function` 
at  `$('#login').validate({`

I don't know is it possible that use another jquery plugin inside jquery class.

Comment: have you tried `jQuery('#login').validate` instead of using `$`?

Comment: Yes. but same result. getting error

Comment: is the path is right? whats output of the `echo theme_js('alcohol.js', true);`?

Comment: and what the reason you make autoevaluated function into your module?

Comment: i made one function which load my js. and this function is theme_js('alcohol.js', true).

Comment: so, it's contains whats in `AlcoholOrder` class? How do you want to use this class?

Comment: implemented fast example from the top of my head, but really don't know how you want to use this class http://jsfiddle.net/sw87W/796/

Comment: I assume something wrong with pathes

Comment: ok i have edited path. there is no issue with path. i think problem with jQuery object and another jquery plugin